# Clamping camera rotation three.js

Tags: javascript, camera, rotation, three.js, clamp

after a long night of messing with quaternions I finally got mouselook working properly on a test game using three.js.

I did notice however that if I continue looking up, the camera flips upside down. I hastily put some code together that works perfectly fine when the user is scrolling relatively leisurely, it just plain doesn't work when the user scrolls fast. I'm probably not clamping the camera rotation correctly, so how would I do that? Or was I somewhat on the right track and just missed something obvious?

A link to the project (source inline): 
http://neveronti.me/WalkingSimulator/

My camera rotation function:

```
//Rotates camera horizontally
y-=mouseMove.x*.02;
//rotates camera vertically
//checks to see if it's moving camera up or down
if(mouseMove.y<0){
    //checks that it's not at the bottom or top
    if(Math.abs(camera.rotation.y*(180/Math.PI))>2 || camera.rotation.x<=0){
        x-=mouseMove.y*.02;
    }
} else if(mouseMove.y>0) {
    if(Math.abs(camera.rotation.y*(180/Math.PI))>2 || camera.rotation.x>=0){
        x-=mouseMove.y*.02;
    }
}
```

My Update Camera function:

```
function updateCamera(){
    camera.lastRotation=camera.quaternion.clone();
    var euler = new THREE.Euler( 0, 0, 0, 'YXZ' );
    euler.x = x;
    euler.y = y;
    euler.z = z;
    mouseMove.x=0;
    mouseMove.y=0;
    camera.quaternion.setFromEuler( euler );
}
```

An image of the problem: [image]

Comment: The fast camera movement makes my eyes hurt! I think it might be a bit too responsive. Other than that, impressive work with quaternions. I never quite understood them myself.

Comment: That's just how I like camera movement. Fast and responsive. In the actual game I would add a slider for it, but in this one it's just a global variable. It took me a solid day of trying to figure out how to work with quaternions, and I still don't understand all of it, but I know a decent amount. As far as the clamping is concerned I'm pretty stumped. Lowering the rotation speed would do the trick, but some people like faster rotation and I have to account for them as well.

Comment: This is unrelated to the problem but I noticed that the speed of the player movement is proportional to the cosine of the angle between the camera view and the plane rather than just constant. I wasn't sure if you noticed that.

Comment: Yeah I noticed that, but one problem at a time

Comment: (1) Way too complicated. You can simplify your camera update like so: `camera.rotation.order = 'YXZ'`;  `function updateCamera() { camera.rotation.set( x, y, z ); }`, but what you are doing likely is not correct. (2) Use `PointerLockControls` instead, as in http://threejs.org/examples/misc_controls_pointerlock.html, or duplicate the approach used therein.

Comment: Good suggestion. That's what I'm going to have to do I suppose.

Comment: Yup, you're completely right on all accounts. As for the update, you're completely right. As for the controls, I basically did just as you said. They use a much better system for the rotation, where they separate the actual movement from the rotation.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's literally been 7 years, but I stumbled across the problem of clamping cameras in ThreeJS (for an fps-style camera), and came up with a solution of my own based on this [stackoveflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72421170/need-help-clamping-camera-rotation). Here is what I came up with:

```js
// make sure to pointer lock for optimal camera feel
const UP_AXIS = new THREE.Vector3(0, 1, 0);
let initialRotation = 0;

this.canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", (e) => {
    let newRotation = this.cameraRotation + e.movementY * -0.00001
    // here is where the clamping takes place
    newRotation = THREE.MathUtils.clamp(newRotation, -Math.PI / 2, Math.PI / 2);

    // rotate the camera horizontally (no clamping)
    this.camera.rotateOnWorldAxis(UP_AXIS, e.movementX * -0.0001 * settings.mouseSensitivity);

    // rotate the camera with clamping
    this.camera.rotateX(newRotation - initialRotation);

    initialRotation = newRotation;
})
```

I hope people find this useful.